# How to reduce the size of React Select in v2

Tags: react-select

The new v2 react-select control is great, but by default is too large. Is there a (preferably) simple way to reduce the height to the same as a standard select control (using Bootstrap v3)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The answer below was given when react-select v2 was in beta, much has changed since then.**

### Read the react-select docs [HERE](https://react-select.com/styles)

React-Select v2 uses emotion CSS-in-JS so the new way to control style over the select components and sub-components is by passing a style object to the `styles` prop. You can also set a className to style with an external stylesheet.

#### CSS-in-JS way

```
const customControlStyles = base => ({
    height: 20,
    minHeight: 20
});

<Select ... styles={{control: customControlStyles}} ... />
```

#### CSS Way `<Select ... className="myClassName" ... />`

```
.myClassName__control {
    height: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get the component to autosize? I have fiddled with many of the css style keys and have come up empty on the relationship between the parts of the component to get it to size width wise based on the contents in the options.

Comment: FYI, there is a min-height set on `control` of 38px. So if you want to go smaller, you need to provide a `minHeight` and not just a `height`. Eg: `styles={{ control: (base, _state) => ({...base, minHeight: '20px', height: '20px'})}}`

Comment: oh my g*d why can't I change `width` or `min-width` with `className`?? Nor with `classNamePrefix`?? I'm going crazy!!!!

Comment: This answer does not work and does not answer the question, which was to reduce the control size, not increase it. If you specify a smaller height, all it will do is reduce the size of the outer div and nothing else inside the control so it will overflow.

Answer (score 17):

Try passing in a value for the maxMenuHeight prop:

```
<Select
  maxMenuHeight={190}
/>
```

see [documentation](https://react-select.com/props)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: no `menuWidth`?? Seesh...I think I'm up to an hour trying to just reduce the size of my React select without adding `<div>`s around it.

Comment: This reduces the size of the menu, not the control. This is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

Setting the `height` property looks like it retains that height even when you have overflow (from multiple selected values spilling onto the next line) so you end up with the values falling outside the box.

I solved this issue by setting the padding top and bottom on the `dropdownIndicator` and the `clearIndicator` and setting `minHeight` on `control` like so:

```js
const styles = {
  control: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    minHeight: 32,
  }),
  dropdownIndicator: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
  }),
  clearIndicator: (base) => ({
    ...base,
    paddingTop: 0,
    paddingBottom: 0,
  }),
};

<Select styles={styles}/>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Worked perfect.  Made this an exported const, and also baked it into a reusable component.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer does not work. All it will do is reduce the size of the outer div and nothing else inside the control so it will overflow.

Comment: Awesome!  This worked for me with one "gotcha".  It seems I can't make it smaller than about 30px.  But it looks a lot better than before and the extra options don't break out of the box.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Adding onto what @craigmichaelmartin commented, the minHeight on `control` is important to overwrite, and it needs to be set at a bunch of places in order to really overcome it.
Here's what worked for me to get it to match the height of a 36px text input element (These settings also work in css, of course)

```js
const customStyles = {
  container: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    display: 'inline-block',
    width: '250px',
    minHeight: '1px',
    textAlign: 'left',
    border: 'none',
  }),
  control: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    border: '2px solid #757575',
    borderRadius: '0',
    minHeight: '1px',
    height: '42px',
  }),
  input: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    minHeight: '1px',
  }),
  dropdownIndicator: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    minHeight: '1px',
    paddingTop: '0',
    paddingBottom: '0',
    color: '#757575',
  }),
  indicatorSeparator: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    minHeight: '1px',
    height: '24px',
  }),
  clearIndicator: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    minHeight: '1px',
  }),
  valueContainer: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    minHeight: '1px',
    height: '40px',
    paddingTop: '0',
    paddingBottom: '0',
  }),
  singleValue: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    minHeight: '1px',
    paddingBottom: '2px',
  }),
};
```

Comment: I also had to set the indicatorsContainer's height in order to make it smaller than the default

Answer (score 3):

You can also try to style the input field of your react-select component, as it can impact the height of the whole react-select component. In my case, this was happening through interference from materializecss.

```
const customStyles = {
  input: styles => {
    return {
      ...styles,
      height: '1.8em'
  };
}
const App = () => (
  <Select
    styles={customStyles}
    options={...}
  />
);
```

Answer (score 3):

From a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218351/changing-height-of-react-select-component/57222937) also on SO, you can modify the `react-select` theme to change the height of the control. Seems easier to me than the other answers.

```
const customThemeFn = (theme) => ({ 
  ...theme,
  spacing: {
    ...theme.spacing,
    controlHeight: 30,
    baseUnit: 2
  }
})

<Select theme={customThemeFn}> ... </Select>
```

For more, see `Theme modifier method` at [this page of the docs](https://react-select.com/props).

Comment: Great answer. This works if using multi-select and want the control height to auto icrease as more options are selected.

Answer (score 2):

### Yet another CSS Way

You can also specify `classNamePrefix` and use it to override CSS styles.

```js
<Select classNamePrefix="mySelect" />
```

```css
.mySelect__value-container{
 height: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. I think the following is the minimal setting. I could able to reduce the `hight` of the react select.

[image]

This is the code, I used TypeScript for this code.

```js
const targetHeight = 30;

const styles = {
  control: (base: any) => ({
    ...base,
    minHeight: 'initial',
  }),
  valueContainer: (base: any) => ({
    ...base,
    height: `${targetHeight - 1 - 1}px`,
    padding: '0 8px',
  }),
  clearIndicator: (base: any) => ({
    ...base,
    padding: `${(targetHeight - 20 - 1 - 1) / 2}px`,
  }),
  dropdownIndicator: (base: any) => ({
    ...base,
    padding: `${(targetHeight - 20 - 1 - 1) / 2}px`,
  }),
};
```

```html
<Select
  styles={styles}
/>
```