# Changing height of react-select component

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using the react-select component along with bootstrap v4

all of bootstraps stuff is based on 35px height it seems, the default height of the `react-select` component is 38px, which looks a little odd.

Any ideas how I can change the height of the component?

It is using some weird JS styling library I have never come across before. I have managed to get it to mimic the outline on focus using it, but the height escapes me, any help much appreceiated

You can play with it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/32lz1kyynm?module=/example.js)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Spending hours, I end up with this to get exact 30px height of react select with border 1px:

```
  const customStyles = {
    control: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      background: '#fff',
      borderColor: '#9e9e9e',
      minHeight: '30px',
      height: '30px',
      boxShadow: state.isFocused ? null : null,
    }),

    valueContainer: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      height: '30px',
      padding: '0 6px'
    }),

    input: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      margin: '0px',
    }),
    indicatorSeparator: state => ({
      display: 'none',
    }),
    indicatorsContainer: (provided, state) => ({
      ...provided,
      height: '30px',
    }),
  };
```

Comment: What is ...provided?

Comment: Provided are the provided styles from `react-select`, if you don't spread them you wouldn't get the default styles for other properties.

Comment: Good stuff. Worked like charm.

Comment: sadly, this disables the growing of the component when it's a Multi-select and there are multiple lines of selected items

Comment: for input property I would add padding: '0px' as well

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated.. considering a different library or implementing the component myself.

Answer (score 40):

You can add your styles to any part of the select components, take a look at the relevant [docs](https://react-select.com/styles#provided-styles-and-state)

here is a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nr67l9p2np) of what you ask for.

In your case the code that you need to add will look something like this:

```
const customStyles = {
  control: base => ({
    ...base,
    height: 35,
    minHeight: 35
  })
};
```

and in the select component:

```
<Select
          className="basic-single"
          classNamePrefix="select"
          defaultValue={colourOptions[0]}
          isDisabled={isDisabled}
          isLoading={isLoading}
          isClearable={isClearable}
          isRtl={isRtl}
          isSearchable={isSearchable}
          name="color"
          options={colourOptions}
          styles={customStyles}
 />
```

Comment: as you can see though, when you decrease the height of just the control to anything less than ~34px, it doesnt actually decrease the size of any other components. I need to, and i imagine original poster, needs to decrease the height of the control while keeping the value centered vertically, the "x" on the right side, etc. i want to decrease everything's height so it's less tall of a rectangle

Comment: How is this upvoted and accepted? It's literally the first thing anyone would think to try, and it doesn't work...

Comment: It could have been more thoughtful if the component could respond to normal bootstrap form control classes for resizing etc.

Comment: This is accepted probably because the demo shows it works.

But, the demo is using version 2.2.0 which is HIGHLY outdated.

The demo, however, is enough to fool the casual lurker.

I agree that this answer should be removed as correct.

Answer (score 12):

The reason why you're not able to make it less than 36px is that the `dropdownIndicator` and `indicatorContainer`(clear icon is displayed) are taking 20px (icon) + 8px padding in all sides. If you reduce that padding, the `minHeight` will actually work.

```js
dropdownIndicator: (styles) => ({
    ...styles,
    paddingTop: 7,
    paddingBottom: 7,
}),
clearIndicator: (styles) => ({
    ...styles,
    paddingTop: 7,
    paddingBottom: 7,
}),
```

You can play around with the padding of the `dropdownIndicator` and `clearIndicator`.

I noticed that you can't go under 30px in minHeight because of the `valueContainer`, unless you change its height/padding.

Comment: this + @erez-lieberman answer work perfect for heights less than 36px

Answer (score 10):

### CSS Way

You can specify `classNamePrefix` and use it to override CSS styles.

```js
<Select classNamePrefix="mySelect" />
```

```css
.mySelect__value-container{
 height: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I was barely able to make the `Select` component as small as 32px (*in my browser*) using the `theme` attribute. It works well when the height is greater than 45px. You can also omit the `baseUnit` attribute.

**It didn't work for small sizes.**

```
  const theme = (theme: Theme) => ({
    ...theme,
    spacing: {
      ...theme.spacing,
      controlHeight: 30,
      baseUnit: 0,
    }
  });
```

```html
<Select options={props.options} theme={theme}/>
```

Comment: This answer works best for me, except I prefer baseUnit to be 2:
 
const customThemeFn = (theme) => ({
    ...theme,
    spacing: {
      ...theme.spacing,
      controlHeight: 30,
      baseUnit: 2
    }
  })

Answer (score 5):

I was able to over write the menu-list's css style:

```css
    /* over write css in react-select module */
    .Select__menu-list {
      max-height: 120px !important;
    }
```

Comment: While this css may help you with the height of the open dropdown, it doesn't change the height of the control, which is the topic of this SO.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to resize the box use this.

```
.create-select {
    width: 160px;
    float: right;
    color: #000;
    [class$="ValueContainer"] {
        min-height: 28px !important;
        max-height: 28px;
    }
    [class$="IndicatorsContainer"] {
        min-height: 28px !important;
        max-height: 28px;
    }
    [class$="-Input"] {
        min-height: 28px !important;
        max-height: 28px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    [class$="-control"] {
        min-height: 28px !important;
        max-height: 28px;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Cause**

The `.control` has a `min-height` of `38px` defined.

**Fix**

Change the `min-height` on the `.control` to your desired height.

```
const customStyles = {
  control: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    minHeight: '30px',
    ...additionalStyles
  }),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to just set the css height property for the class
`__value-container`

Here is the code:

```
.react-select__value-container {
    height: 3rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const customStyles = {
  control: (provided: Record<string, unknown>, state: any) => ({
    ...provided,
    height: 42,
    boxShadow: 'none',
    borderColor: 'none',
    '&:hover': {
      color: '#60B3D1'
    },
    border: state.isFocused ? '1.5px solid #60B3D1' : '1.5px solid #cbd5e1'
  }),
  option: (styles: any, state: any) => ({
    ...styles,
    color: state.isSelected ? '#FFF' : styles.color,
    backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? '#60B3D1' : styles.color,
    borderBottom: '1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125)',
    '&:hover': {
      color: '#FFF',
      backgroundColor: '#60B3D1'
    }
  }),
  input: (base: any) => ({
    ...base,
    'input:focus': {
      boxShadow: 'none',
      border: '1px solid #60B3D1'
    }
  }),
  menuPortal: (base: any) => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999 })
}


<Select styles={customStyles } />
```

This really works well for me

Answer (score 0):

for react select input view you can use styles like this :

```
<Select
....
styles={{
          control: (styles) => ({
            ...styles,
            height: "40px",
            backgroundColor: "white",
            borderRadius: "4px",
            outline: 0,
            border: 0
          }),
        }}
/>
```

and for menu height you can use this one :

```
<select 
        maxMenuHeight={200}
        minMenuHeight={10}
/>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the simplest way in 2024:

```
<Select 
    options={templateOptions} 
    onChange={onTemplateSelect}
    maxMenuHeight={100} // set max height of dropdown
/>
```

That's it. All the styles remain present, just the dropdown menu has its height fixed. Increase/decrease the value to match your desired outcome